# Give column A when you find text string in column B

Tags: excel

I have two sheets. One sheet contains column `A` and column `B`.  `A` contains names, `B` contains a list of names. My second sheet contains names where I need to find if any of the names in my second sheet appear in column `B`, and if they do, what is the name in column `A`.

For example:

Sheet1:

```
A1: Nancy
B1: Kyle (243), Jack (524), Foster (4352)
A2: Bill
B2: Cathy (23423), Tim (1019)
```

Sheet2:

```
A1: Kyle (243)
B1: Nancy
A2:Tim (1019)
B2:Bill
```

I know how to use vlookup/index/match when the text matches exactly. But I can't get it to approximate search for text string correctly. Countif can only tell me, yes, that search string exists in that column but not which row. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use MATCH with wildcards:

```
=INDEX(Sheet1!A:A,MATCH("*"& A1 &"*",Sheet1!B:B,0))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! at first I was going to say it doesn't work, but I was putting the whole range of columns in the index instead of just the column I needed. I also tried match by itself and it gave me errors so I thought I was doing something wrong. Why does this work???

Comment: the match should work on its own.  It should return the row number where the first match is found.  and returns that to the INDEX.  Please mark as correct by clicking on the check mark by the answer.